# Upgrading to DXA 2.2 CMS from 2.0 with 'Framework-only' option on SDL Web 8.5

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa2.2, dxa-upgrade

We have a DXA 2.0 implementation where we pared down the DXA installation, removing almost entirely the Core module, leaving only the Framework Folder, and a couple of Schemas/configuration Components from Core which are necessary for DXA to work - so basically we have a 'Framework-only' assets of DXA.

We now want to upgrade to DXA 2.2, as DXA 2.2 also supports 'Framework-only' option (with the implementation of this [idea](https://community.sdl.com/ideas/sdl-tridion-ideas/i/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas/framework-only-option-for-dxa-installupgrade)), this option is ideal for us.

However, looking at the import packages of the DXA installation, this option seems to be supported only for the SDL Site 9.x versions and not with SDL Web 8.5.

i) **Sites 9 import packages**

[image]

ii) **SDL Web 8 import packages**

[image]

I can't find anything specific about this on [SDL DXA docs](https://docs.sdl.com/784837/718319/sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-2/upgrading-------------dxa-on-the-------------sdl-tridion-sites-content-manager/GUID-C76398AE-D80E-476E-A020-4B42F8EF6875), I was expecting 'framework-only' option to be supported also with SDL Web 8.5/8.6 versions.

Am I missing something? any thoughts?

Comment: AFAIK - that option only introduced in DXA 2.1+  Sites 9.0+ , In the DXA 2.2 if that file does not exist for 8.5 then it seems only available for sites 9.0+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Velu pointed out, support for 'framework-only' is only added for the Tridion Sites 9.x version.

It turns out CMS part of DXA 2.2 mainly contains additional changes required to support Sites 9.x versions (e.g. native regions support).

So it is not necessarily required to upgrade this part(from 2.0), if you're still using SDL Web 8.5/8.6 version.

Answer (score 0):

For web 8.5, I have updated my sandbox environment with necessary publications and created a package very similar to framework only. You can modify the import powershell script and import this custom package OR framework-only.zip to other 8.5 environments. It is important to place the DXA application definition file on the target CM server before you run content porter or your PowerShell.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @Shiva, it is indeed possible the way you've suggested, essence of question was , if it is OOTB supported for 8.6/6 version.